# What does the value of the column 'roles' mean in whois result

Tags: whois

When I check up an IP with whois tool, I'll get the result with one of the columns named 'roles'. The value of the 'roles' column can be 'abuse', 'technical' or 'administrative'.
It's easy to understand the meaning of 'technical' and 'administrative', but is there anyone who know what does 'abuse' mean here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`role` may be used to determine the type of contact that the node describes. There are several types of contacts, such as: administrative, technical, owner, etc.

The term "abuse" refers to a recipient that is intended to report complaints about possible illegal use of that IP address. For example, if the IP is used to send SPAM emails, or as part of some kind of frauds.

This is similar to the [scope of the `abuse@` email](https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/343.html) in a domain.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps me a lot!